# Does Google Analytics not track data accurately when reporting the same pages to multiple accounts?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, tracking, statistics

I am reporting my traffic to 2 different Google Analytics accounts.

Using Universal Analytics, I am doing something like:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('create', 'UA-YYYY', 'auto', {'name': 'community'});
ga('community.send', 'pageview');
```

I see data flowing in on both accounts, however I see the numbers don't exactly match.

I can see about 16% less page views in the "community".

I declare my account only in this one spot. Also after looking at the OS/Browser section and the content drilldown section, I don't see any specific drop anywhere. It seems to be spread across users seemingly randomly.

Is this a known issue?